# Link to Chilling Effects on questions taken down by DMCA

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, copyright, copyright-infringement

I ran across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558800/minimum-number-of-steps-needed-for-a-frog-to-reach-at-position-x (10k) today, and was surprised that it was deleted. Turns out it was the subject of a [takedown notice](https://www.chillingeffects.org/notices/10901013).

Since SE is sending these to Chilling Effects, can we link to the takedown notice on the deleted-question 404 page?

[image]

Additionally, for those of us *with* 10k, it would be great to see the same thing in the body of the post, even if it's in a simple blockquote.

Comment: Would kinda like to avoid making body edits for stuff like this. We try to always leave a comment explaining the reason for deletion, both for the benefit of the author and for moderators or anyone else reviewing the deletion. Agree that a link from the 404 page *would* be handy for everyone else.

Comment: @Shog9 My thought is that if there's a link on the 404 page, what's keeping the system from auto-embedding it at the top of the post, like duplicate notices?

Comment: Well, that's something else... If we wanted to implement these, we'd need a more rigorous method of *marking* these posts as DMCA-deleted - so, why not a post notice? Kill two birds with one stone...

Comment: That'd be even better, and probably easier to implement too

Comment: I wonder how long the cached question will remain on Google? ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's Google's problem ;)

Comment: How come 10k users can see this? Doesn't that still count as SE republishing the material? @Shog9

Comment: What do I look like, a lawyer? We don't have hard-delete without messing with the database directly, and that's reserved for questions involving boats, @Josh. Ain't like we can take back data-dumps in any case, and those aren't limited to 10K users.

Comment: inb4 someone sends a DMCA takedown notice to Internet Archive, demanding to remove the SE data dump because of the number of steps needed for a frog to reach some position.

Comment: @Shog9 You do have hard-deletion of revisions, which would suffice.

Comment: Not anymore, @Normal. That too was dangerous.